# GridView in one of the fragments in swipey tabs (horizontal scroll) android

Tags: android, gridview

I implemented this swipey tabs code from google name "viewpager meets swipey tabs". now for fragments activity each is set with xml layout. i want this activity to display a grid view. i tried implementing the grid view example explained on http://developer.android.com but it gives some errors for findgridviewbyid and imageadapter constructor on gridview.setAdapter. 
how can i implement grid view to display images in this fragment only.

```
public class StockTabFragment extends Fragment {

  public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
    StockTabFragment f = new StockTabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_tab_fragment, null);

    return root;
  }

  private ViewGroup createGridView(ViewGroup root) {
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {                
        Toast.makeText(StockTabFragment.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    return root;
  }
}
```

Stock_Tab_Fragment.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
      />
```

Comment: Can you please post stock_tab_fragment.xml and also show where you are calling createGridView?

Comment: edit: posted the layout for this stock tab..how do i call create grid view? m just a beginner with android and OOP. that's why i need help with the code. thanks for the reply